# Openlayers infinite loop called when clear()

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, openlayers-6

I created the function that enable selection of feature from map, with 2 functions thats are called when I click on feature or when I click on map (no feature selected)

E.G

```js
select = new ol.interaction.Select({
  toggleCondition: this.isMultipleSelectionEnable
    ? null
    : ol.events.condition.never,
  style: selectedStyle
})
this.select = select
map.addInteraction(select)
this.selectedFeatures = select.getFeatures()
```

Here are my functions

`this.selectedFeatures.on(['add'] function() {}  // add feature to map)`
and
`this.selectedFeatures.on(['remove']function(){this.map.clear())`

This works well when I click on my map, but whenever I call the function clear() to clear `selectedFeatures` from another component, it automaticly calls the 'remove' function from OL, making an infinite loop.

How can I resolve this?
How can we can we clear the selected features from the map, without triggering the "remove" function from OL?
Or can we call directly the 'remove' from another component?

Comment: We will probably need a [repro] here because this library seems to be pretty scoped and you may have a hard-time getting hits with this question otherwise.